# WYSISYG PDF Creator

Tags: java, jquery, pdf, wysiwyg

I want to allow users to create a PDF file with an online WYSISYG editor . It will be basically images and text that they can drop and create PDF.I will create a UI using jquery-ui .

I came across [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) that seems to be a good solution.But is there any other way or existing open source project ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [an wysiwyg editor](http://www.tinymce.com/) and [html2pdf](http://html2pdf.fr/en)